# rules=rows doesn't work in php

Tags: php, html, css, styles

Hi guys :) I am trying to make rows after every row of table, it works when it is in HTML, after i put it in PHP it doesn't work :(

```
<div id="table">
<table width="100%" border="0" rules="rows">
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdad</td>
    <td>asdadasda</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>dasdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdas</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>adasdasdasd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code which works and this is my PHP code in which rules=rows doesn't works

```
echo '<div id="table" align="center">';
        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" rules="rows">';
    echo '<tr class="bb">';
    echo '<td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>';
    echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
    echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
    echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
    echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

That's all my code :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="clock">
<!--<div id="txt"></div>-->
</div>
<!--<div id="table">
<table width="100%" border="0" rules="rows">
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdad</td>
    <td>asdadasda</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>dasdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdas</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>adasdasdasd</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>sdasdasda</td>
    <td>dasdasda</td>
    <td>sdasdasda</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="bb">
    <td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>
    <td>asdasdasd</td>
    <td>asdasda</td>
    <td>dadasdad</td>
    <td>asdadasd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>-->
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)

    {
echo '<html><body><div id="table" align="center">';
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" rules="rows">';
echo '<tr class="bb">';
echo '<td><div id="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '</tr>';
        }

?>
</table>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen? How does anything happen at all if you have `border="0"`? Have you considered using CSS instead?

Comment: Make sure you are not missing .php extension on using php ?

Comment: Your PHP is outputting HTML. Your browser can't tell the different between the HTML outputted by the PHP and HTML loaded from a static file. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: This PHP part is inf for() and i think it is the problem

Comment: can you show us all the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a table everytime the for loops.

you shold have something like this:

```
<?php
echo '<html><body><div id="table" align="center">';
echo '<table width="100%" border="0" rules="rows">';
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
 {
echo '<tr class="bb">';
echo '<td><div class="tdheight">asdasd</div></td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '<td>asdasd</td>';
echo '</tr>';
        }

?>
</table>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

You should also change the id attribute to a class one since it will be multiple elements with the same id